# CCSpriteBatchNode addChild?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access, ccsprite, ccspritebatchnode

Is it possible to add a child to a CCSpriteBatchNode that was itself added as a child of the batch node? Pretty much I have lets say spriteA that I want to be in a relative location to spriteB when I do a CCAction for it. spriteB was added as a child of the batch node. Now can I have spriteA added as a child of spriteB or no?

Edit: It seems I am getting this crash because spriteA doesn't have the same texture as spriteB. So how would I have spriteB added as a child to spriteA even though they have different textures?

Right now I am trying this and I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[CCSpriteExtended addChild:z:tag:], /cocos2d/CCSprite.m:568
```

Is this possible or no? I just always want spriteA in a relative location to spriteB even when it is moving around the screen. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sprites in a SpriteBatchNode should use the same texture. So what you want to do isn't possible.

You might want to override update and manually position spriteA relatively to B

Comment: Can you provide an example, I am still a little bit confused. Thanks!